# Fortran array addition goes wrong

Tags: arrays, fortran, addition

I'm trying to add two arrays, but for some reason the target array only contains zeros. 
When i compile and run the program i don't get any errors, but the output file is wrong.
In the code i call dhscf which fills the arrays Gnaatm and Gnascf with values, i (try) to save those in gavenaa and gavenas, and the call dhscf again to get new values for Gnaatm an Gnascf. When i write all those arrays to files gavenas en gavenaa seem to be empty although Gnaatm and Gnascf aren't.

The code i'm using is:

module var

```
   real(dp), dimension(:), allocatable :: Gnaatm(:), Gnascf(:), gavenaa(:), &
 & gavenas(:)
```

end module

grdsam.f:

```
allocate (Gnaatm(nasize))
allocate (Gnascf(nasize))
allocate (gavenaa(nasize))
allocate (gavenas(nasize))

    call dhscf(.....)
    gavenaa = Gnaatm 
        gavenas = Gnascf

    do ipt = 1, npt

      call dhscf(....)
       gavenaa = Gnaatm + gavenaa
       gavenas = Gnascf + gavenas
    enddo

open(unit=12, file="Zgavenaatm.txt", status="replace")
  do iwrite = 1, nasize
    write(12, *), iwrite, gavenaa(iwrite), Gnaatm(iwrite) 
  enddo
close(12)

open(unit=12, file="Zgavenascf.txt", status="replace")
  do iwrite = 1, nasize
    write(12, *), iwrite, gavenas(iwrite), Gnascf(iwrite) 
  enddo
close(12)

deallocate (Gnaatm)
deallocate (Gnascf)
deallocate (gavenaa)
deallocate (gavenas)
```

end grdsam

When i run the program i don't get errors, but the output file is wrong. Typical output is like this:

```
      10   0.0000000000000000      -2.35488624992556957E-015
      11   0.0000000000000000      -4.75822627213221874E-017
      12   0.0000000000000000      -7.16040821425613171E-014
      13   0.0000000000000000       8.33283089385797112E-021
      14   0.0000000000000000      -1.04121906025281556E-014
```

The second column only contains zeros, but the third column does contain numbers. 
So the arrays 'Gnaatm' and 'Gnascf' contain numbers, but somehow adding them to 'gavenaa' and 'gavenas' goes wrong. Can any one tell me what i'm doing wrong?

ps. i'm using the gfortran compiler on Ubuntu 12.

Comment: I think the problem resides in your subroutine `dhscf`... don't see any mistakes in what you have posted so far.

Comment: If you are not already doing so, try compiling with maximum debugging options and see if the compiler can help find the problem.  With gfortran I suggest: -O2  -fimplicit-none  -Wall  -Wline-truncation  -Wcharacter-truncation  -Wsurprising  -Waliasing  -Wimplicit-interface  -Wunused-parameter  -fwhole-file  -fcheck=all  -std=f2008  -pedantic  -fbacktrace

Comment: Well, i found the error. Somewhere in the code i overlooked an if-statement, which caused my problem. Thanks for all the help though!

Answer (score 3):

I would be really surprised if any fortran compiler had issues with something as basic as adding up two arrays, so either the code shown is not exactly the code you're using, or the problem is in parts of the code that are omitted.

First, you don't show it here, so I'll ask it: do you have `implicit none` in your code? Continuing without it would be a waste of time; it avoids many "silly" errors, like misspelled variable names.

Second, have you tried the old-fashioned debugging method of writing (parts of) the arrays you're interested in to the screen? Just put in some statements like

```
write(*,*) gavenaa(:5)
```

immediately after an assignment statement, to see if the arrays ever contain values you expect.

If you still can't find the place where things go wrong, try to reduce the code to a minimal, but complete, example that exhibits the same problem. Often the mistake will be found while doing this, but if not, it is much easier for others to help you if you can give them some code that is complete and compiles directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just doing whole array assignments why are you bothering with `forall` constructs ?  Since all the arrays in question have the same size you could simplify this block:

```
gavenaa(1:nasize) = Gnaatm(1:nasize)
forall(icount = 1:nasize) 
    gavenas(icount) = Gnascf(icount) + gavenas(icount)
end forall
```

to

```
gavenaa = Gnaatm
gavenas = Gnascf + gavenas
```

Likewise in the rest of your code.

I can't say that your use of the `forall` is incorrect, but it seems unnecessary and slimming your code down a bit will help you, and us, to properly diagnose and fix whatever problem you have.